# Sharepoint word document saving issue

Tags: sharepoint-server

There is a shared document that needs to be quarterly edited by different people, as we all upload our edits - it seems like I can only see and upload mine. While everyone else is for the most part fine. It doesn't change the document everyone else is completing. Also I recently updated to Windows 10.. can that be the issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Did the issue only occur on you? Did the issue occur on one document or other documents?

And did the issue occur on SharePoint 2013, SharePoint 2016 or other version?

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Clear office upload center cache. Go to Start->Search-> type “Office Upload Center”->settings->delete cached files.
2. Check if other users save the word successfully.
3. Upload a new document to the document library and check if the same issue will occur.

More references:

[Overview of co-authoring in SharePoint Server.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/co-authoring-overview)

[Document collaboration and co-authoring.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/document-collaboration-and-co-authoring-ee1509b4-1f6e-401e-b04a-782d26f564a4?ocmsassetID=HA102772333&CTT=1&CorrelationId=3799c04c-f48d-4f60-9891-491c6b67dac4&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)